# How can I clone photo after tick button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a mini web site, and I have some troubles. Can anybody help me :(

My goals are that when I click the plus icon, I will be able to choose an image from my local file system, and then when I click on the ✔ symbol at the bottom, this image will be cloned in the gray area below. I'm sharing my code with you. Thank you for everything.

Comment: Hi. Please format your code properly. It's all over the place, and difficult to read.

Comment: Bülent Bey ben VS Code üzerinden çalışıyorum. En/ Mr. Bülent I working on VS Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do an image assignment from one element to another using the `src` attribute:

```
document.getElementById("previewimga").src = document.getElementById("previewimg").src;
```